# What is the sequence field in mdl_course_sections in the Moodle Database?

Tags: php, sequence, moodle

I am trying to insert things by PHP code into the course sections every time I call my method to create a course but I came across the 'sequence' field. What is it and how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence field in the course_section table is the course_module id of the modules added to the  section of the course.

Hope this helps.

regards
gnuwings

Comment: Thank you, would it be safe to assume that this field would be empty when I create a new course?

Comment: Not always. The first section will have a non-zero value which corresponds to the course_module id of the default activity(news forum).